# What is happening with this code? Why am I allowed to iterate until 335?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, operating-system

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        printf("%p %d %d", &array[i], array[i], i);

    return 0;
}
```

Which output:

```
0x7fff5b0b0ac0 0 0
....... blahblah
0x7fff5b0b0fe4 0 329
0x7fff5b0b0fe8 0 330
0x7fff5b0b0fec 0 331
0x7fff5b0b0ff0 0 332
0x7fff5b0b0ff4 0 333
0x7fff5b0b0ff8 0 334
0x7fff5b0b0ffc 0 335
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I tried to compile and it **always** stop on 335 what is happening here? Is it linked to my hardware? (Macbook Air "13)? Please explain me, I am a lay person.

Thanks

Comment: missing closing paren in your printf statement?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? man.... there are ton of errors in the code and tell me what you really want to do?

Comment: I think we lost some code.... printf statement isn't complete

Comment: It stopped at 172 for me. 335 is just your lucky number.

Comment: It will depends of your hardware

Comment: 2 words: undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok we got it. You are really smart and know a ton of things so you can make fun of newcomers. What you find obvious isn't for everyone. Go outside and get a life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A segmentation fault occurs when your code tries to access some memory but is unable to do so. This could be because of memory protection. In general, operating systems will have memory protection built in to prevent unauthorised programs from accessing sensitive bits of memory, planting malicious code and/or executing said malicious code with elevated privileges.

The specific number of 335 is likely related how much memory your program got allocated. This will vary depending on a number of factors, including hardware and operating system. To give you an example, I ran your code on Codepad, and this is the output: [Codepad](http://codepad.org/pzD00WVX)

```
0xff9bc704 0 0
0xff9bc708 1 1
0xff9bc70c 2 2
0xff9bc710 3 3
0xff9bc714 4 4
0xff9bc718 -16121856 5
0xff9bc71c -6568128 6
0xff9bc720 -143041244 7
...
0xff9bdcf0 0 1403
0xff9bdcf4 0 1404
0xff9bdcf8 0 1405
0xff9bdcfc
Segmentation fault
```

As you can see, it got much further on Codepad than it did on your machine. You can also see that some addresses already contained other values. These are present because they don't belong to your program, something else put them there. If a chunk of code was stored there, then your code could potentially go and execute it (and do bad things).

Answer (score 4):

Accessing your array out-of-bounds leads to undefined behavior. So accessing `array[5]` could already create a segmentation fault - it's undefined. That in your case accessing `array[335]` is resulting in the memory violation, is just random. Try it on a different machine and it may behave differently.

> behaviour, such as might arise upon use of an erroneous program
>   construct or erroneous data, for which this International Standard
>   imposes no requirements 3.

Comment: Is there an explanation about why this program stops after 335 iterations exactly? (Even if I recompile multiple times)

Comment: No, undefined behavior is just undefined. You can try to restart your computer, change compiler settings/optimization or build configuration (Debug/Release) and your number 335 may change. But it's not guaranteed to be anything - the only thing that is guaranteed, is that it won't be less than 5!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be accessing array out of bound.

```
int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

    for( i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); i++)
        printf("%p %d %d\n", &array[i],array[i],i);
```